Block Embeddings of Classical Groups Inducing Embeddings of Symmetric Spaces
Families of certain classical groups induce families of (irreducible) symmetric spaces.
Let $(G_r)_r$ be such a family of classical groups, e.g. $G_r=\mathrm{Sp}_{2r}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\iota_r:G_r\to G_{r+1}$ denote the block embedding $A\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&&\\&A&\\&&1\end{pmatrix}$. There exist maximal compact subgroups $K_r$ of $G_r$ such that $\iota_r(K_r)\subset K_{r+1}$ for all $r$, so we obtain an induced map $\iota_{r,*}:X_r\to X_{r+1}$, where $X_r=G_r/K_r$ denotes the symmetric space associated to $G_r$.
Question: Is this induced map $\iota_{r,*}$ a smooth embedding?
Any help, including references, would be appreciated, since I am not too familiar with this kind of math. Thanks!

After some searching, I was able to solve this.
The condition $\iota_r(K_r)\subset K_{r+1}$ is not enough, we need to assume $\iota_r^{-1}(K_{r+1})=K_r$. This is possible for classical groups since they are reductive and one can take $K_r$ to be $G_r$ intersected with the unitary group of the appropriate dimension.
Then it is an exercise in point-set topology to prove that $\iota_{r,*}$ is a topological embedding.
To prove that it is a smooth embedding, we have to prove that it is a smooth immersion, for which we can just apply the Equivariant Rank Theorem.
